# How to convert __value enum from VS2003 to VS2010

Tags: c++-cli

I have this code snippet from VS2003, Managed C++ and I want to rewrite it in the 2010 C++/CLI way but the newer compiler doesn't accept the 'feature_all' enumeration.. Can someone tell me how to convert it correctly?

This is the snippet in VS 2003:

```
    [Flags]
    __value enum Features: unsigned int
    {
        feature_1 = 1,
        feature_2 = 2,
        feature_3 = 4,
        feature_all = feature_1 | feature_2 | feature_3   // accepted by compiler
    };
```

I tried writing it like this in VS 2010:

```
    [FlagsAttribute]
    value class enum Features: unsigned int {
        feature1 = 1,
        feature2 = 2,
        feature3 = 4,
        feature_all = feature_1 | feature_2 | feature_3   // not accepted by compiler
    };
```

But the second is definitely not working...

The compiler returns 7 Errors: (C2332, C2236, 3x C2065, C2056 and C3115)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper keyword is *enum class*, also adopted in C++11:

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum class Features: int {
    feature1 = 1,
    feature2 = 2,
    feature3 = 4,
    feature_all = feature1 | feature2 | feature3 
};
```

Note how I also removed the mysterious underscores, assumed that you want to make this enum type visible to other .NET projects and wanted it to be CLS compliant so it can be consumed by languages that don't support unsigned types.  *int* is the default and can be omitted.  Tweak as needed.